# Drush 9 on Windows 7 problem

Tags: drush

I installed drush 9 and now I'm getting the following error whenever I run a drush command:

```
/usr/bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/mysite/vendor/drush/drush/drush.launcher: No such file or directory
```

Details:

- I have installed drush 9 on Windows 7 using `composer`. This was an update to my previous drush 8.
- The drush files are installed in my local site's `vendor` directory.
- The `drush.launcher` file is in the directory indicated in the above error message.
- To run a drush command, I go to my site's root directory using `MINGW64` and run the command using `vendor/bin/drush`. for example:

```
vendor/bin/drush drusn --version
```

- I have `C:\mysite\vendor\bin` in my `path` environment variable.
- I don't want to use `drush.launcher` at this time but not sure why it gets invoked and yet not found.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I have posted an initial answer below. In general it's easier to help if you provide as much info as possible - the exact version of Drush and Drupal, the environment you are running it in (Cygwin on Windows I assume) and so on.

Comment: Thanks @hansfn. This is part of my effort to update my Drupal 8.1.x to 8.6.15 which requires drush 9. Should I have updated Drupal before installing drush 9?

Comment: No, but you are aware that you should use Composer to update Drupal 8, not Drush? Anyway, if you had indeed correctly upgraded to Drush 9 there should be no drush.launcher.

Comment: @hansfn sorry for the confusion. I _am_ using Composer to update Drupal 8. Drush is listed in my composer.json as a dependency with ^9.0.0 but I've had no luck getting it to work.

Comment: To repeat myself (as in my answer below). There should be no `vendor/drush/drush/drush.launcher`. What version does `composer info drush/drush` return?

Comment: @hansfn I have reverted my drush back to 8.0.5 so that I could start from scratch. So `composer info drush/drush` shows 8.0.5. At this point my issues are to do with getting composer to update both drush and Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drush 9 doesn't come with `drush.launcher` so something is wrong with your Drush installation / update. You should try to fix that by updating or reinstalling Drush. However, in the meantime just delete `drush.launcher`.

PS! It's recommended to install [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) in addition to the site-local Drush.

Comment: thanks for your hint about `drush.launcher` and that my drush installation is not correct. I still have issues with updating my drush but I'll mark this as an answer since I'm now dealing with a different type of issue.